# Convergence of random probability measures.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

This question is motivated by the standard definition of convergence in probability, although applied in a different way...

Suppose that I have $V_n = V(W_1,...,W_n)$ for $i=1,...,n$ where $W_i$ are iid random variables. Suppose further that I have another random variable $W$ such that $W\sim W_i$. Further define a function $f(V_n,W)\geq 0$ such that I know for all fixed $\epsilon >0$, I have that

$$ P_W\{f(V_n,W) > \epsilon\} \xrightarrow{p} 0, $$

as $n\rightarrow \infty$. Then does this imply that $f(V_n,W) \xrightarrow{p} 0$?

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean
$$ P_W \left( f(V_n,W) > \epsilon \right) \rightarrow 0,$$
as it seems weird for a probability to go in probability to zero. Notice that by definition of convergence in probability it must hold that
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow\infty} P_W \left( | f(V_n,W) | \geq \epsilon \right) =0.$$
As $f(\cdot)$ is non-negative by definition it goes in probability to zero.

Comment: No I do not, since $W_1,...,W_n$ are independent of $W$, therefore if I take the probability with respect to the probability measure of $W$, I still have a random element to the problem. One can think of $P_W(f(V_n,W)>\epsilon) = P_{W|W_1,...,W_n}(f(V_n,W)>\epsilon)$, the conditional probability of $W$ given $W_1,...,W_n$, however since $W_i$ is independent of $W$, we can just focus on the probability measure with respect to $W$.